# Prove $V_1\otimes...\otimes V_d$ is a subspace of the vector space...

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove $V_1\otimes...\otimes V_d$ is a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{K}^{V_1\times ...\times V_d}=\{f:V_1^*\times...\times V_d^*\rightarrow\mathbb{K}\}$

**Definition:** Let $\mathbb{K}$ a field and $V_1...V_d$ vector spaces of finite dimension over $\mathbb{K}$. We define the tensor product  space
$V_1\times...\times V_d$ as the set:
$V_1\otimes ...\otimes V_d=\{f:V_1^*\times...\times V_d^*\}$ where $f$ is multilinear.

**Note:** $V^*$ refers to the dual space.

Let $f,g\in V_1\otimes...\otimes,V_d$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{K}$, $\alpha f + g \in \mathbb{K}^{V_1\times \dotsb \times V_d}$ because $\mathbb{K}^{V_1\times \dotsb \times V_d}$ is a vector space. I only need show $\alpha f+g$ is multilineal.
For hypothesis $f,g$ are multilineal. How can i show $\alpha f+g$ is multilineal?

I'm stuck here, can someone help me?

Comment: For the inclusion $V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_d \hookrightarrow \Bbb K^{V_1 \times \cdots V_n}$, one just maps $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ to $(f_1, \ldots, f_n) \mapsto (f_1(v_1), \ldots, f_n(v_n))$.